# remove all local javascript file except external javascript files in php

Tags: php, regex

i am writing a php script that compress local javascript files into one from an html page. Now i want to delete local references except external javascript files.

for example, i have following variables.

```
$my_domain = "mysite";
$base_url ="http://www.mysite.com"
```

I want to delete all local javascript references except external. local javascript include sub-domain too. For Example, http://www.mysite.com/script/jquery.js and http://dev.mysite.com/scripts/test.js is the example of local javascript files.

i want to use regular expression for this.

EDIT:
The format is :

```
 <script src="http://www.mysite.com/jsfile.js"></script>
```

EDIT 2:
 The script in a page is like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/test/example/Scripts/superfish/js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/test/example/Scripts/superfish/js/superfish.js"></script>
```

where `$baseURL="http://localhost/test/example";`

it is currently not replacing.

Comment: You should tell the format of your javascript. Are you using this pattern: `<A HREF="javascript:myfunction()">Click Here</A>` or what? So we can provide you a more accurate regex.

Comment: @Vantomex update question accordingliy.

Comment: Do you want to delete every SCRIPT tags containing such a URL, or just remove domain/base url part?

Comment: I mean, do you want to make them become, e.g. `src="jsfile.js"` without any domain or base url in it?

Comment: @Vantomex yes i want to delete script tag. The src may contain full url or subdomain or just file name.

Comment: oops, I forgot to escape the dot, I will update my answer.

Comment: Show us what you have so far so we can help you along.

Comment: You say "I want to use regular expression for this," but I suggest that may not be the best way to do it.  Regular expressions are not a magic wand that you just wave at every programming problem that happens to involve strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your base url is **mysite.com**, this regex:

Search for: `(<script\b[^[><]*\ssrc\s*=\s*["'])(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www.)?(?:\w+\.)?\bmysite\.com/?\b([^><"']*["'])`

Replace with: `$1$2`

will make your URL references (can contain any number of domains/subdomains), e.g. from **http://www.mysite.com/jsfile.js** become **jsfile.js**

Supposing you want to remove every SCRIPT tags (and their contents) containing such a url, use this regex:

Search for: `<script\b[^><]*\ssrc\s*=\s*[^><]*\bmysite\.com\b[^><]*>\s*<\/script>`

Replace with: nothing

If there is a possibility that between `<script>` and `</script>` can contain any text, use this regex instead:

Search for: `<script\b[^><]*\ssrc\s*=\s*[^><]*\bmysite\.com\b[^><]*>.*?<\/script>`

Replace with: nothing

So

```
<?php
$ptn = "/<;script\b[^>;<;]*\ssrc\s*=\s*[^>;<;]*\bmysite\.com\b[^>;<;]*>;.*?<;\/script>;/";
$str = "<;script src="http://www.mysite.com/jsfile.js">;<;/script>;";
$rpltxt = "";
echo preg_replace($ptn, $rpltxt, $str);
?>
```

Comment: I have optimized the second regex and have added additional note.

Comment: Supposing you mentioned the regex library or application you are currently using is, I can even make further optimization.

Comment: i have tried this, but not working.$replacePattern = "<script\b[^[><]*\ssrc\s*=\s*[\"'](?:http:\/\/)?(?:www.)?(?:\w+\.)?\bmysite.com/?\b[^><]*>\s*<\/script>";
 echo preg_replace($replacePattern, '', $html);

Comment: So, you use PHP, this is the last regex `result = subject.replace(/<script\b[^><]*\ssrc\s*=\s*[^><]*\bmysite.com\b[^><]*>.*?<\/script>/g, "");`

Comment: this also return nothing. although $html contains whole page html.

Comment: Sorry, it was javascript regex. For PHP, it is $result = preg_replace('%<script\b[^><]*\ssrc\s*=\s*[^><]*\bmysite.com\b[^><]*>.*?</script>%', bla bla bla);

Comment: If so, just replace `mysite.com` with `localhost`. Maybe there is some character in my regex that should be escaped. I don't know PHP convention to escape forbidden character in regex.

Comment: i replaced mysite.com from your regular expression with "localhost" but still it is not removing.

Comment: I have edited a bit, and I think it works now for you. I made the last PHP regex using the tool from this website: `http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm` You also can put my other regex in this website to convert them into PHP regex. Don't forget to replace mysite.com to localhost it is your case.